# nil value returned by NSClassFromString swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following code in my project to draw fading on a view:

```
let customBlurClass: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("_UICustomBlurEffect")!
let customBlurObject: NSObject.Type = customBlurClass as! NSObject.Type
self.blurEffect = customBlurObject.init() as! UIBlurEffect
self.blurEffect.setValue(1.0, forKeyPath: "scale")
self.blurEffect.setValue(radius, forKeyPath: "blurRadius")
super.init(effect: radius == 0 ? nil : self.blurEffect)
```

sometimes on Fabric I get crash report from the app on this line:

```
let customBlurClass: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("_UICustomBlurEffect")!
```

which means that the **NSClassFromString** return nil value,

I searched a lot about this problem but no useful answers,

Please Help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that those crashes occur on devices running iOS 8 or earlier. `_UICustomBlurEffect` was introduced in iOS 9.

You should do:

```
if let blurClass = NSClassFromString("_UICustomBlurEffect") {
    // set up blur view
}
```

to avoid crashes on devices where it's not supported.